# How to plot date times over a day - Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to import and plot date times that go past midnight. The input dataset did not have date times attached so I had to reformat the column so that timestamps after midnight carried over to the day. This is drawing an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

d = ({
    'Time' : ['0/1/1900 8:10:00', '0/1/1900 12:10:00', '0/1/1900 22:10:00', '1/1/1900 1:10:00'],                 
    'Value' : [1,2,3,4],                                
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df.plot(x='Time', y='Value')
formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: time data '0/1/1900 8:10:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

I understand these don't match. But I'm not sure what would be the most efficient workaround. Could I add a day? Or is there a better way to just input timestamps and add 24 hours to timestamps after midnight?

Comment: if that is your real data the issue seems to be the zeroth January.

Comment: @erkandem, I understand this doesn't match. I had to _create_ the date times via formatting. This is the output I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "0/1/1900" is not a correctly formatted date ("1/1/1900" would be fine). We can increment the day of the month by one:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

d = ({
    'Time' : ['0/1/1900 8:10:00', '0/1/1900 12:10:00', '0/1/1900 22:10:00', '1/1/1900 1:10:00'],                 
    'Value' : [1,2,3,4],                                
     })
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['Time'] = ['/'.join([str(int(x.split('/')[0])+1)] + x.split('/')[1:]) for x in d['Time']]

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df.plot(x='Time', y='Value')
formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @perl. But I'm hoping to use the `date time` to `plot` values past midnight last. So the value value should be at `8:00:00` and the last one should be at `01:00:00`

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. How do you create the dates? Can you change it to start from '1/1/1900' instead of '0/1/1900'?

Comment: @jonboy: I've updated with the line of code that adds one day to your dates in string format before converting to datetimes. Would that work for you?